# Xcode, Swift; Detect hyperlink click in UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink, uiwebview, shouldstartload

I made an iOS app with Xcode and Swift.

I want to open specific hyperlinks in Safari browser, there others in the WebView itself.

To reach this, I'll have to check when an hyperlinks gets clicked.

This is the code I have so far:

```
//
//  PushViewController.swift
//  App
//
//

import UIKit
class PushViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var openpushmessage: UIWebView!

    var weburl:String = "http://www.example.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: weburl)!
        let requestURL: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        openpushmessage.loadRequest(requestURL)
    }
    override func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if navigationType == .linkClicked
        {
            print("You clicked a hypelink!")
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

The code in `viewDidLoad()` opens the loads the main URL (http://www.example.com) from my server. That works fine.

`override fun webView[…]` should detect if a hyperlink is clicked and then `print("You clicked a hypelink!")`.

But unfortunately I'm getting the following errors:

[image: one error and one warning for my code]

What am I doing wrong? How to get rid of these errors?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project ? Also remove the override keyword.

Comment: @Priyal Okay, I removed `override` and I cleaned the project but still the same. I'm now additionally getting: `Use of undeclared type 'URLRequest'`

Comment: I copied your exact code. Resolved the suggestions after which final code is : 

`func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if navigationType == .linkClicked
        {
            print("You clicked a hypelink!")
        }
        return true
    }` and it doesn't give any error or warnings. 

I am using **swift3** so had to resolve warnings.

Comment: which swift version are you using ?

Comment: I'm still using Swift 2. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with swift2 but one thing you can try is to delete your method and copy it from UIWebViewDelegate. Also try comparing with UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the working solution (Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2):

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if request.URL?.query?.rangeOfString("target=external") != nil {
        if let url = request.URL {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Many thanks to [danhhgl from freelancer.com](https://www.freelancer.com/u/danhhgl.html)!

Answer (score 7):

please try

for swift 3.0

```
 public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
        {
         if navigationType == .linkClicked
         {

            }
            return true;
        }
```

swift 2.2

```
internal func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {
        if navigationType == .LinkClicked
        {

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting `Extraneous '_' in parameter: 'webView' has no keyword argument name` and `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIWebViewNavigationType' and '_'`.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2?

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Do you know how to convert it to Swift 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve with this code:

```
 function reportBackToObjectiveC(string)
 {
 var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.setAttribute("src", "callback://" + string);
 document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
 iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
 iframe = null;
 }

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
links[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    reportBackToObjectiveC("link-clicked");
}, true);
}
```

in ios code:

```
if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"callback"]) {
[self setNavigationLeavingCurrentPage:YES];
return NO;
}
```

More details you can check from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397340/4935811):

Answer (score -1):

With Xcode v15.0 I had to make the following adjustments to get the link activated working:

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: WKNavigationType) -> Bool {
   if navigationType == .linkActivated {}
   return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `if` statement? Why the semicolon after the `return` statement? What does this have to do with Xcode 15? Also, there is no such delegate method for `WKWebView`, it's for `UIWebView`.